# How to detect if the clock is set to 12 or 24 hours time format in unity/C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do you detect if the operating system's clock (the one shown in the task bar) is configured to 12 or 24 hours time format in Unity/C#?

Unfortunately `DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.ShortTimePattern` is of no use because it uses the systems current culture, which can differ from the configured clock format. Do you have any ideas how to get the systems currently active clock format?

Comment: do you mean like in the taskbar?

Comment: @Daniel, yes, the clock in the taskbar.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134985/cultureinfo-datetimeinfo-how-to-check-if-is-24-hour-time

Comment: Hello Daniel, thank you for sharing the link. Unfortunately neither of the two approaches described in it are usable. ShortTimePattern as mentioned above and DateTimeFormatInfo.AMDesignator because it's always set (at least on OSX).

Answer (score 2):

In windows you can get the Short time format string from the registry. At least on my machine, this is what the system clock in the tray uses:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International\sShortTime`

If the value contains a lower-case `'h'`, then it's displaying the `AM/PM` format. Otherwise it's the `24-hour` format (which uses an upper-case `'H'` for the hour).

Here's a method that reads the key and returns `true` if it's in the 24-hour format (note that for the `Registry` class you need `using Microsoft.Win32;` in your namespace):

```
private static string GetSystemTimeFormat()
{
    return Registry
        .GetValue(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International", "sShortTime", "x")
        .ToString()
        .Contains("h")
        ? "AM/PM"
        : "24-hour";
}
```

To test it I ran the following code:

```
private static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Currently the system clock is {GetSystemTimeFormat()} format");

    GetKeyFromUser("Change the format and press any key to try again...");

    Console.WriteLine($"Now the system clock is {GetSystemTimeFormat()} format");

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}

private static ConsoleKeyInfo GetKeyFromUser(string prompt)
{
    Console.Write(prompt);
    var key = Console.ReadKey();
    Console.WriteLine();
    return key;
}
```

Then, after the prompt, I changed the "Short time" here (which I got to by right-clicking on the clock and choosing "Adjust date/time"):

[image: ![enter image description here]

And the output was the following (which matched correctly with what the clock looked like in the tray):

[image]

Comment: Hello Rufus, thank you very much for sharing this! Is there a cross platform approach? The project is also build for iOS, Android and OSX, hence a xcross platform approach would be more appreciated. Well, at least windows can be handled this way. So again, thank you.

Comment: Ah, I'm not sure about that. I did see some articles on Android when I was searching, though. But this won't work for those...

Comment: @SePröbläm You're not going to find a cross-platform answer.

Comment: @Draco18s: I was afraid of that. Strange though, configuring a time seems to be a rather common requirement...

Comment: @SePröbläm Yes, but every OS is going to do it differently.